# How to extract javascript contents

Tags: javascript

As we extract html contents using

```
alert(document.all[0].innerHTML);
```

how can i extract javascript contents.

Anyone who knows the answer, please help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What are the exact problems you are having with this? http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I have a .js file where it has only functions in it, in one of the function i want to extract the contents of that same .js file and display it.  can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
alert(firstScript.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thank u, approach s almost near  but my file itself is .js file where there will be no <script> tag.  please tell me how can i extract .js file contents where there will be only functions in it and no tags

Comment: You have to make an ajax call to get the contents of your external script. Using jquery(faster to write example) would go like this: `$.get('/js/yourscript.js', function(data){alert(data)})`. Beware of the cross-domain limitations.

Comment: If the OP wants to extract all the JS from the page, this won't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started) to grab the script's contents--they are not automatically exposed to an API when a script tag is added--only executed. But if you are thinking of executing the code later on, you could use `eval()` to do so, but bearing in mind that this can cause security problems for your site if the code is obtained in whole or part from untrusted sources.